# TextInput event onContentSizeChange not firing

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make my `TextInput` grow in height when the entered text reaches the second line. However I don't receive an event when my text gets wrapped to the second line (without using a new line character). This results in partial hiding of the text within the input.

From the documentation I can not find any event which returns content size besides `onContentSizeChange`.

I am testing on an Android device.

I can not upgrade React-Native, I am stuck on `0.58.1`

```
class SomeComponent extends React.component 
{
    ...
    handleContentSizeChange = (event) => {
        console.log('Handling contentSizeChange');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput ... multiline={true} onContentSizeChange={this.handleContentSizeChange}/>
        )
    }
}
```

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.4
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 882.73 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 11.8.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.8.0/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.5.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.8.0/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.4, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 21, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29
        Build Tools: 27.0.0, 27.0.3, 28.0.0, 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.0
        System Images: android-22 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, chromeos-67 | Chrome OS 67
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 11.4.1/11E503a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
      react-native: 0.58.1 => 0.58.1 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `onContentSizeChange` at all. The height should increase automatically as you type, provided you haven't fixed a height for the input or have limited it by fixed heights of the components around it.

Comment: thank you, there was a height defined by the surrounding component.